# Laravel 5.2 : DB Records fetch and check id in another table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent

Suppose I have `tableA` and `tableB` with models,

What i want is to fetch records from `tableA` and check the `id's` of `tableA` in `tableB`.

Suppose that `tableA` have `title` column, What i want is that show all the titles.

And if the `id`'s  of `tableA` is in `tableB` then show a check sign if not then show cross sign in the beginning of the titles.

Can't find a way out.

Comment: Did you applied foreign key constraint ?

Comment: Yes the foreign key constraint are applied .

Comment: Have you tried something like this: Table1::with(["table2"]);

Comment: Yes :
`$rewards = Reward::all();
foreach ($rewards as $reward){
            $list = User::with('unlocks')->where('id','=', Auth::user()->id)->first();
        }
`
And the relationship is :

`public function unlocks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\RewardUnlocked','user_id');
    }`

Comment: Try without where : User::with('unlocks')->first();

Comment: Also you should put all code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use joins?

```
TableA::query()
    ->select("tableA.*, tableB.id as checked")
    ->leftJoin("tableB","tableA.id","=","tableB.id")
    ->get();
```

So if there is no `id` in tableB, `checked` will be empty.

Comment: By the way, if all you want is to show checked or unchecked, why don't you have just a column in `tableA` for that?